How to work with SAR and optical images? Trying to do a Multimodal CNN
I´ve been trying to come up with a image classification algorithm that uses SAR and optical images, but I havent been able to write a code that works, where could I look for guides about multimodal models or maybe a code I so I could guide myself a little?
